# Поменять порядок расположения элементов внутри массива на обратный

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
String text = "Каждый охотник желает знать, где сидит фазан";

String[] colors = text.split(",?\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
{
    String result = colors[i];
    colors[i] = colors[colors.length - i - 1];
    colors[colors.length - i - 1] = result;
    System.out.println(colors[i]);
}
```

В консоли он выдаёт: "фазан сидит где", а необходимо, чтоб он выдавал всю фразу из colors.
"фазан сидит где знать желает охотник Каждый".
Не понимаю, где именно ошибка. Что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length / 2; i++)
{
    String result = colors[i];
    colors[i] = colors[colors.length - i - 1];
    colors[colors.length - i - 1] = result;
}
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(colors[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "Каждый охотник желает знать, где сидит фазан";

List<String> colors = Arrays.stream(text.split(",?\\s+")).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.reverse(colors);
colors.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы проходите цикл по всему массиву, при этом одновременно меняя 2 элемента

```
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length / 2; i++) {
    String result = colors[i];
    colors[i] = colors[colors.length - i - 1];
    colors[colors.length - i - 1] = result;
}
```

Так же можно создать 2й массив куда будете записывать значения

```
    String text = "Каждый охотник желает знать, где сидит фазан";

    String[] colors = text.split(",?\\s+");
    String[] result = new String[colors.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        result[i] = colors[colors.length - i - 1];
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
```

Или воспользоваться `Collections.reverse` из библиотек `java.util.Collections` + `java.util.Arrays`

```
String text = "Каждый охотник желает знать, где сидит фазан";

String[] colors = text.split(",?\\s+");
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(colors)); 
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(colors));
```

[***Ссылка на источник***](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/reverse-an-array-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

А я вот так решил задачу. Тут вам и вывод сразу в одном цикле и замена элементов местами, что собственно и требовалось сделать:

```
String text = "Каждый Охотник Желает Знать, Где Сидит Фазан";
        String[] colors = text.split(",?\\s+");

        String temp = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
        {
            if (i <= (colors.length / 2)) {
                temp = colors[i];
                colors[i] = colors[colors.length - i -1];
                System.out.println(colors[i]); //
                colors[colors.length - i - 1] = temp;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(colors[i]); //
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "Каждый охотник желает знать, где сидит фазан.";
String[] textArray = text.split(",?\\s+");
String temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length / 2; i++)
    {
        temp = textArray[i];
        textArray[i] = textArray[textArray.length - 1 - i];
        textArray[textArray.length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
```

После этого в textArray будет массив "наоборот". В твоем примере в принципе все верно, но не нужно проходить по всем элементам массива. Только до половины, далее уже пойдут заменённые тобой элементы.